# Quarkus Kafka consumer doesn't work in native mode

Tags: apache-kafka, graalvm, quarkus

I have a Quarkus Kafka consumer. In VM mode it works well.

After I build native runner with :
./mvnw  package -Pnative

when I run it in native mode I have this exception :

```java
2019-05-23 17:17:42,340 ERROR [io.sma.rea.mes.imp.LegacyConfiguredStreamFactory] (main) Unable to create the publisher or subscriber during initialization: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at io.smallrye.config.ImplicitConverters$StaticMethodConverter.convert(ImplicitConverters.java:99)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.convert(SmallRyeConfig.java:133)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.getValue(SmallRyeConfig.java:76)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.impl.ConnectorConfig.getValue(ConnectorConfig.java:57)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.spi.ConfigurationHelper.asJsonObject(ConfigurationHelper.java:51)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.KafkaSource.<init>(KafkaSource.java:35)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.KafkaMessagingProvider.getPublisherBuilder(KafkaMessagingProvider.java:40)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.KafkaMessagingProvider_ClientProxy.getPublisherBuilder(Unknown Source)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.impl.LegacyConfiguredStreamFactory.createPublisherBuilder(LegacyConfiguredStreamFactory.java:119)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.impl.LegacyConfiguredStreamFactory.lambda$initialize$2(LegacyConfiguredStreamFactory.java:100)
        at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.impl.LegacyConfiguredStreamFactory.initialize(LegacyConfiguredStreamFactory.java:100)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.impl.LegacyConfiguredStreamFactory_ClientProxy.initialize(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.extension.MediatorManager.initializeAndRun(MediatorManager.java:103)
        at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.extension.MediatorManager_ClientProxy.initializeAndRun(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.reactivemessaging.runtime.SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle.onApplicationStart(SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle.java:18)
        at io.quarkus.smallrye.reactivemessaging.runtime.SmallRyeReactiveMessagingLifecycle_Observer_onApplicationStart_4e8937813d9e8faff65c3c07f88fa96615b70e70.notify(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl$Notifier.notify(EventImpl.java:244)
        at io.quarkus.arc.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:85)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.LifecycleEventRunner.fireStartupEvent(LifecycleEventRunner.java:39)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ArcDeploymentTemplate.handleLifecycleEvents(ArcDeploymentTemplate.java:115)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.LifecycleEventsBuildStep$startupEvent20.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl1.doStart(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.run(Application.java:213)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.smallrye.config.ImplicitConverters$StaticMethodConverter.convert(ImplicitConverters.java:97)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
        ... 30 more
```

Comment: I've been told this was a bug that is fixed in the current master of Quarkus. Will be part of the 0.16 release next week

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug [2221](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/2221) already fixed with this [PR](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/2418) since version 0.16.

Try any new Quarkus release to fix it.